# 2 UIcollectionview in 1 UIviewcontroller with 2 different UIcollectionflowlayout?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

may I know is there any way to implement 2 UIcollectionview in 1 UIviewcontroller with 2 different UIcollectionflow layout. 
The main issue is one UIcollectionview is conform to iOS UIcollectionviewflowlayout and the other is conform to a Waterfalllayout. Because the problem I faced now is I cant have both delegate functions in one UIviewcontroller. Thanks all.

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: WaterfallLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    }
```

Comment: _I cant have both delegate functions in one UIviewcontroller_ - why?

Comment: you need to check who is caller of delegation function

Comment: updated the question, do you guys think its possible?

Comment: no, you should use only one delegate method inside ViewController, but inside method you can figure out what layout called it... see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     //: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

class Controller: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, WaterfallLayoutDelegate {

    let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    let waterfallCollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero)

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

        waterfallCollectionView.delegate = self
        let waterfallLayout = WaterfallLayout()
        waterfallLayout.delegate = self
        waterfallCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = waterfallLayout
    }

    //MARK: - WaterfallLayoutDelegate

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: WaterfallLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize.zero
    }

    //MARK: - UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

        return CGSize.zero
    }
}

//MARK: - Just for test

protocol WaterfallLayoutDelegate: class {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout: WaterfallLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
}

class WaterfallLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    weak var delegate: WaterfallLayoutDelegate?
}
```

Everything just works.

Comment: if I conform to WaterfallLayoutDelegate, then its required me to conform to the delegate, how should I just use one sizeForItemAt for 2 collectionview and different flowlayout.
And the Waterfalllayout.self is failed.

Comment: and i will get the error below if I use both delegate stubs

Method 'collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)' with Objective-C selector 'collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAt:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector

Comment: are `Waterfalllayout` inherits from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`?

Comment: can you show me interface `Waterfalllayout` class and `WaterfallLayoutDelegate` protocol?

Comment: bro are you free to open a chat room for me to discuss with you? Sorry for that.

Comment: https://github.com/sgr-ksmt/WaterfallLayout/blob/master/Sources/WaterfallLayout.swift

Comment: `WaterfallLayout` inherits from `UICollectionViewLayout` not from `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`... and `WaterfallLayoutDelegate` absolutely custom protocol not related with `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`... In that case you should use methods from both protocols (like you write in your question)

Comment: but if follow to what i written in question it will hit this
""Method 'collectionView(_:layout:sizeForItemAt:)' with Objective-C selector 'collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAt:' conflicts with previous declaration with the same Objective-C selector"""

Comment: sorry, my question edited. Their signature is similar

Comment: then you can take the delegate from the controller to a separate class `WaterfallLayoutDelegateHandler` for example and conform it to `WaterfallLayoutDelegate` protocol... and add to your view controller property of this type...

Comment: erm I am new to Swift, I not really understand what you mean here. Can provide me a simple example?

Comment: your answer seems like mimic the waterfall layout library into a new class, then how to use the protocol and delegates?

Comment: no, everything should just work without conflicts... I created mocks for `WaterfallLayoutDelegate` and `WaterfallLayout` just for test.. you should use your original classes

Comment: by reading your sample, seems no need to create a delegate handler right? still remain my view controller with 2 flow layout delegate function